# Compute $P(X>40\; |\; X>10)$ where $X$ has an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Please could someone advise if I have interpreted this problem correctly

Let $X$ have an exponential distribution  with a mean of $i = 20$

**(1) Compute $P(X>40 \;| \;X>10)$**

I believe the correct solution here is to find $P(X>40)$ because of the inclusion / exclusion principle. That is if we define the event $A = P(X>40)$ and the event $B = P(X>10)$. In addition, define $A \cap B$ as $P(X>10)$. Then to compute (1) we find the following $P(X>40) \cup P(X>10) - P(X>10)$ which is

$$1- (1-e^{-\frac{30}{20}})=0.2231$$

**EDIT**
Due to the "memorylessness" of the probability distribution

$$P(X>40 \mid X>10)= P(X>30) $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, I think you meant to define $A=\{X>40\}$ and $B=\{X>10\}$. Then you can't _define_ $A\cap B$, because it is already decided by $A$ and $B$. In particular $
A\cap B=A$, because $B\subseteq A$. Second, unions are to be put between sets and not numbers, i.e. $P(X>40)\cup P(X>10)$ does not make sense. Third, note that the exponential distribution has the [memorylessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness) property.

Comment: +1 Stefan ..Thanks for the heads up about memorylessness

Comment: Are you having trouble calculating $P(X>30)$?

Comment: If you do, look at the cumulative distribution function of the exponential function.

Comment: Is there still a question here?

Comment: I am not sure. Is the edited solution above incorrect?

Comment: It is correct. $ $

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/354480/77033) (but which is a duplicate of which?)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, due to "memorylessness" of an exponential distribution, if $s>0$, $t>0$, then
$$P(X>s+t\mid X>s) = P(X>t) = e^{-\lambda t}.$$

We can find that if we simply calculate the expression, the result will show the "memorylessness":

$$
\begin{align}
P(X>s+t\mid X>s) &= \frac{P\big(X>s+t\cap X>s\big)}{P(X>s)} = \frac{P(X>s+t)}{P(X>s)} 
\\
&= \frac{\int_{s+t}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx}{\int_{s}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx} = e^{-\lambda t} = P(X>t),\quad (s>0,t>0).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $\cap$ is used between sets, not numbers and hence $P(X>s+t)\cap P(X>s)$ does not make sense. The correct notation is $P(\{X>s+t\}\cap\{X>s\})$ or in short-hand notation $P(X>s+t,X>s)$.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thank you for the correction.