# Memorylessness of the Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Please help me solve the following question with two parts.

$T$ is the time required to repair a machine. We have that $T$ is exponentially distributed with a mean of $\frac{1}{2}$ hours.

For the first part of the question, I am asked to find the probability that repair time exceeds $\frac{1}{2}$ hours. I find
$$P(T> \frac{1}{2})= \frac{1}{e}$$

I am a bit stuck on the second part to the question:
"What is the probability that a repair takes at least 12.5 hours given that its duration exceeds 12 hours"?

I was thinking the answer is

$$P(T\geq 12.5 \, | \, T>12)=P(T\geq .5) = \frac{1}{e} \, \text{ ,}$$

since exponential distribution is memoryless. Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Would this just equal $\frac{1}{e}$, like the first part?

Comment: $P(T\ge{12.5}|T\gt{12})=\frac{P(T\ge{12.5})}{P(T\gt{12})}$.  And yes, since it is memoryless, = $P(T\ge{.5})$.

Comment: Yes, the answer to the second part is also $\frac{1}{e}$. As a practical, non-mathematical, issue, I would worry that the _conditioning_ event $\{T > 12\}$ is such a rare event that the exponential model might not be a good fit to the real-life problem any more.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/275795/77033) (but which is a duplicate of which?)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: this would seem to be the duplicate of the other. Once one is closed, we could merge the answers, but that seems to be unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct, this is indeed what is meant by memorylessness.

In general, for all $s\geq 0$, $t \geq 0$, we have

$$P(T>s+t\mid T>s) = P(T>t) = e^{-\lambda t}.$$

We can prove the memorylessness by transforming the expression on the LHS using the definition of conditional probability, as follows

$$
\begin{align}
P(X>s+t\mid X>s) &= \frac{P\big(X>s+t\cap X>s\big)}{P(X>s)} = \frac{P(X>s+t)}{P(X>s)} 
\\
&= \frac{\int_{s+t}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx}{\int_{s}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx}= \frac{0- -e^{-\lambda (s+t)}}{0- -e^{-\lambda s}} = e^{-\lambda t} =  P(X>t)
\end{align}
$$

Accreditation: This is a slight modification of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/377020/77033) by Tianyu Zheng

Comment: Because I have made this answer a community wiki post, I feel I can ask for an upvote, so please upvote this to 1. This will enable me to suggest to close the linked question in the comments as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: But this question would seem to be the duplicate, being asked 3 months after [the other](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/275795).

Comment: @robjohn thanks for your reply. I realise time order is regarded as important when closing as duplicate, but I've never quite understood why, though maybe it is to prevent [this kind of situation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12936/77033). In the other question, the OP is unclear about more than one thing and I would say the mistake about the events there will usually only distract users. Jeff seems to approve of my strategy [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1760/77033).